# Retrieving Map from List of Maps using for loop

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I've created List of Maps using the following

```
List<Map<Object, String>> postModel = new ArrayList<>();
```

I just started out with java and not able to figure out how to retrieve the individual Map key value. 
It would be great if you could point me to some documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you need to have a List of Map ? You should probably edit to explain your requirement if you are a rookie in Java.

Comment: String value = postModel.get(0).get("key");

Comment: I would recommend you to create **Map<Object, String>** inside an object. By making list of map you are unnecessary increasing code complexity and decreasing readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through every `Map` in the `List` and get the [entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) of each, something like this:

```
for(Map<Object, String> map : postModel){
    for(Map.Entry<Object, String> entry : map.entrySet(){
        entry.getKey();
        entry.getValue();
        // you can add the condition you want here
        // and return the pair key-value after wrapping this with a method
    }
}
```

Moreover, if you want a particular `Key` itself in the `Map` at a particular index in the `List`, you can create a method and use the [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) like this for example:

```
Object getKey(int index, String key){
    for(Object k : postModel.get(index).keySet()){
        if(k.toString().equals(key)){
            return k;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Lastly if you want only the `Value` of a given `Key` of a particular `Map`, you simply get it like this:

```
String getValue(int index, Object key){
    postModel.get(index).get(key); // or you really don't need to wrap it
}
```